# Jquery Slide Box Menu hidden in ie 8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

I've built the following site www.marshallareastagecompany.org, and it looks fine in any of the newer browsers, however it seems no matter what i do the navigation gets hidden behind the main image in IE7,8, and i can't seem to fix it.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this one's a bit tricky I found one way (at least in developer tools) to fix it and that's to get rid of `position:relative` on the image and set it's `padding-top` to `15px` rather than using `top`

So the img would become

```
<img style="z-index: 1; display: block; padding-top: 15px" class="center" title="MacBeth" alt="MacBeth" src="/public/images/CurrentPlayWide.png"/>
```